# Visual Studio 2017 ошибка подписи

Tags: visual-studio

При запуске выдало ошибку `"При подписи произошла ошибка: Не удалось подписать bin\Debug\app.publish\HTTP_Server.exe. SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria"`
Никакие сертификаты до сих пор не использовал. Откуда это взялось? Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что проект не ваш. По этому проверьте данный пункт:

1. Заходим в свойства `Проекта`
2. Переходим в `Подписывание`
3. Снимите галочку с `Подписать манифесты ClickOnce`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скиньте ваш проект, я хочу посмотреть что у вас там такого.